# Преоброзавать строчку в массив

Tags: php, массивы

допустим у меня есть строчки 4-10;5-30;6-77. Как их преобразовать в такой массив:

```
$array = [
    4 => 10,
    5 => 30,
    6 => 77
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
$str = '4-10;5-30;6-77';

$arr = explode(';', $str);
$arr = array_reduce($arr, function($res, $item) {
    $tempArr = explode('-', $item);
    $res[$tempArr[0]] = $tempArr[1];
    return $res;
}, []);
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо, всё прекрасно работает.

Comment: @ГлебЧерных Если ответ Вам помог, то ставьте галочку рядом с ответом, чтобы его принять и другие пользователи смогли его найти в случае возникновения похожей задачи. спасибо!

Comment: Галочку поставил, спасибо еще раз :)